# Did Sentinel 2 L2A products significantly improve since 2021?

Tags: sentinel-2, harmonize

We have a project for detecting vegetation change/vitality in Switzerland (NDVI/NBR based), where a few years ago, we decided against Sentinel 2 L2A products since there were a few known issues, e.g. overcorrection in steep terrain as documented in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/401723/34517).

Since the question of using L1C or L2A arose anew because of Landsat compatibility, I am wondering: **Have there been significant improvements in the Sen2Cor algorithms 2021 up to now (2023) that would justify revisiting this decision?**

I tried getting some info out of the current [quality report](https://sentinel.esa.int/documents/247904/0/OMPC.CS.DQR.002.06-2023%20-%20i63r0%20-%20MSI%20L2A%20DQR%20July%202023/c1b6ad17-6f9a-3bee-1021-d0d127346f01) and can tell that things have happened (e.g. updates in the processing baseline Dez. 2022), however as an "only occasional" user, I feel like I'm not able to judge: Did these updates bring significant improvements for (which?) actual applications, e.g. solving abovementioned problems? How do practitioners respond to these updates?